# New regex module fuzzy function error value. Python

Tags: python, regex, syntax-error, fuzzy-search, pypi-regex

im trying out the fuzzy function of the new regex module.  in this case, i want there to find a match for all strings with <= 1 errors, but i'm having trouble with it

```
import regex

statement = 'eol the dark elf'
test_1 = 'the dark'
test_2 = 'the darc' 
test_3 = 'the black'

print regex.search('{}'.format(test_1),statement).group(0) #works

>>> 'the dark' 

print regex.search('{}'.format(test_1){e<=1},statement).group(0)

>>> print regex.search('{}'.format(test_1){e<=1},statement).group(0) #doesn't work 
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i have also tried

```
print regex.search('(?:drk){e<=1}',statement).group(0) #works
>>> 'dark'
```

but this . . .

```
print regex.search(('(?:{}){e<=1}'.format(test_1)),statement).group(0) #doesn't work
>>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: after `serach` you need only one `(`. It should be so: `print regex.search('(?:{}){e<=1}'.format(test_1)).group(0)`

Comment: where do you put the string being searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet, you forgot to put the `{e<=1}` in a string. In your final snippet, I think the problem is, that `format` tries to deal with the `{e<=1}` itself. So either you use concatenation:

```
print regex.search(test_1 + '{e<=1}', statement).group(0)
```

or you escape the literal braces, by doubling them:

```
print regex.search('{}{{e<=1}}'.format(test_1), statement).group(0)
```

This can then easily be extended to

```
print regex.search('{}{{e<={}}}'.format(test_1, num_of_errors), statement).group(0)
```

Comment: i'm a little confused on how to make the error number a variable.  lets say error = 2 ... it doesn't work when i try '{e<={}}'.format(error)

Comment: @draconisthe0ry I just realized, literal braces can be escaped by doubling them. I'll edit the answer